# I want no NULL values in CASE

Tags: plsql, null, case

I'm using PL/SQL Developer and I want the column NEW_UPDATED to only display 'New in Last 30 Days' or 'Updated in Last 30 Days'
I have NULL values for records that fall outside that range and are not NEW or UPDATED and I don't want these records

```
CASE 
    WHEN live_date >= SYSDATE - 30 THEN
    'New in Last 30 Days'
    WHEN release_date >= SYSDATE - 30 THEN
    'Updated in Last 30 Days'
END AS NEW_UPDATED
```

Comment: Q: Have you tried adding an "ELSE" to your CASE expression?

Comment: If you don't want NULL values to show, you'd need to exclude those rows from being output by your query. You'd do that by adding a predicate to the query along the lines of `live_date >= sysdate - 30 or release_date >= sysdate - 30`